# Phonegap, Cordova - Issue with Plugins

Tags: javascript, ios, plugins, cordova

I have installed Phonegap (3.0.3) and the Cordova CLI.

I am also running iOS as a platform (confirmed using `$ cordova platforms ls`)

I have installed the plugins (`$ cordova plugins ls`)

```
org.apache.cordova.core.dialogs
org.apache.cordova.core.vibration
```

However, when I run this console command (`$ cordova emulate ios`), I get the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion", referenced from:
      _playBeep in CDVNotification.o
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      _playBeep in CDVNotification.o
  "_AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      _soundCompletionCallback in CDVNotification.o
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      _playBeep in CDVNotification.o
      -[CDVVibration vibrate:] in CDVVibration.o
  "_AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion", referenced from:
      _soundCompletionCallback in CDVNotification.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386
(1 failure)
```

I have followed the directions from the API page here (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) and below is my config.xml file in the `MyApp > www > config.xml` file which causes the error.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.myapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />   
</widget>
```

Any suggestions what the issue might be, and how I can go about fixing it?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 14):

Add AudioToolbox framework in your Xcode project:

Your Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries

Click the '+' button

Choose AudioToolbox.framework

Comment: I'm using cordova-plugin-dialogs, this works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `cordova build ios`?

then `cordova emulate ios`

This error happen when you don't add the source to the Compile sources in build phase. 
Try to add plugins with :

TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CDVNotification.h - the #import lines tell you everything you need to add to your compile sources build phase.

Foundation/Foundation.h
UIKit/UIKit.h
AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h

Add those 3, and it will compile.

UPDATE - an additional change is necessary in CDVNotification.m

playBeep() calls soundCompletionCallback()
soundCompletionCallback calls playBeep()

In order for playBeep to be error free, soundCompletionCallback must be declared.  The simple solution is to declare it before playBeep, then define it after.

Add this line just before static void playBeep(int count)

```
// declared but not defined to avoid undeclared error in playBeep
static void soundCompletionCallback(SystemSoundID  ssid, void* data);
```